# Problema de Plugin creado en WordPress y Visualizacion con Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, elementor

Estoy teniendo un problema con un plugin que estoy creando, dejo el código del plugin, lo que quiero realizar es poder insertar las etiquetas de Facebook, Google, Google Tag Manager, desde el panel de administración de WordPress pero al momento de activar el plugin si utilizo Elementor se le remueven los estilos al header adjunto una pantalla.[image: Errror al activar mi plugin y estar usando elementor]

[image: Captura del formulario y menu de administracion en WordPress que utilizo en mi Plugin]

Y acá dejo el código utilizado:

**Index.php**

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Tag Marketing
Description: Crea un menú de configuración para que insertes los ID de tu Pixel de Facebook y Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager
Author: Manuel Ramírez Coronel
Author URI: https://github.com/racmanuel
*/

add_action("admin_menu", "plugin_menu");

function plugin_menu() {
  add_menu_page('Tag Marketing', 'Tag Marketing', 'manage_options', 'menu_config_pie', 'registrar_tags', 'dashicons-code-standards');
}
function registrar_tags() {
  //must check that the user has the required capability 
  if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
  }else{
    if($_POST && $_POST['ID_Pixel_FB']) {
      $texto = $_POST['ID_Pixel_FB'];
      if(update_option('Pixel_FB', $texto)) {
        echo '<p>Las etiquetas han sido activadas.</p>';
      } else {
        echo '<p>No se pudo configurar las etiquetas.</p>';
      }
    }
    include('formulario.php');
  }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'agregar_en_head');

function agregar_en_head() {
  if($pixel_fb = get_option('Pixel_FB')) {
    ?>
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  ! function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
    if (f.fbq) return;
    n = f.fbq = function () {
      n.callMethod ?
        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
    };
    if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];
    t = b.createElement(e);
    t.async = !0;
    t.src = v;
    s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
  }(window, document, 'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '<?php echo $pixel_fb;?>');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id='<?php echo $pixel_fb?>'&ev=PageView
&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code --
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

**formulario.php**

```
<h1 class="wrapper">Configuración de Tags de Marketing</h1>
<form method="post">
  <p>
    Identificador del píxel de Facebook:
    <input type="text" name="ID_Pixel_FB" value="<?php echo ($valor_option = get_option('Pixel_FB'))? $valor_option : ''; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Guardar">
  </p>
</form>
```

Dejo el link del repositorio por si alguien esta interesado en contribuir:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://github.com/racmanuel/tag-marketing/blob/main/index.php)

Comment: No entiendo el problema cual es, creo que deberías aportar mas información para poder entender lo que pasa. Saludos

Comment: Quedo solucionado fue un error en un punto y coma en el codigo PHP.